# Firebase Persistence mode never syncs to server (Android)

Tags: android, firebase

I am developing a new Android app using Firebase (first time to use Firebase). and I opted to use the Persistence mode as it suits my app better. 
My problem is that the app doesn't sync data to the server, hence, other devices, even if the device used to store data is online!!

Code is fine (as far as I can tell), if I disable the Persistence mode, everything works fine, but for sure I don't have the cached data on the device.

This happens in different devices and emulator as well, and the weird thing is that sometimes the devices sync, and then stop syncing again, for no reason!

I appreciate any recommendations here.

code:

```
My App class:
//....
        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
        Firebase.getDefaultConfig().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
        Firebase.getDefaultConfig().setLogLevel(Logger.Level.DEBUG);
//...
```

Sending code in Message class:

```
//....
    Firebase senderRef = new Firebase(MyApp.FirebaseURL).child("Messages").child(sender_Id);
    senderRef.keepSynced(true);
    senderRef.push().setValue(this, null);
//....
```

receive code:

```
//...

        Firebase ref = new Firebase(MyApp.FirebaseURL).child("Messages").child(sender_Id);
        Query query = ref.orderByKey();

        query.limitToLast(MAX_CHAT_MESSAGES_TO_SHOW);
        query.keepSynced(true);

        query.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                Log.d("Firebase", "Message Child Added");
                Message message = dataSnapshot.getValue(Message.class);
                mMessages.add(0, message);
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
//...
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue with iOS. Did you ever solve this?

Comment: not yet unfortunately, I disabled the offline mode for now, however I am still in development mode.

Answer (score 0):

I have done in both ways:

1. If you **want** to **sync** with **firebase server**

   ```
   FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().goOnline();
   ```
2. If you **do not want** to **sync** with **firebase server**

   ```
   FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().goOffline();
   ```

**Full code:**

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);

        /**
         * User anyone function from below as required,
         * Read comment proper
         */

        // If you want to sync with firebase server
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().goOnline();

        // If you do not want to sync with firebase server
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().goOffline();
    }
}
```

Hope this would help you.